# Ubuntu 15.10 won't shut down or reboot

Tags: shutdown, 15.10, reboot

I recently bought a new lenovo B50-10 notebook on which I've installed ubuntu 15.10 successfully, at least I thought so until I stumbled upon a troublesome issue : my notebook won't shut down. Every time I would try to shut down the purple-ish screen with the ubuntu logo and the little dots would come out as usual but it will freeze after 2 dots turned orange. Before this I had a different problem : shutting down would only make the screen black( not switched off) and the fan and the powerlight would still be on; after reinstalling ubuntu it changed to the freezing problem I mentioned above. 
this is a cry for help, the problem it's really bugging me out and I fear having to continuously use the power button to force power off may damage my notebook on the long run.
thanks to anyone who would be so kind to help.

p.s.
I've already tried several solutions like modifying grub file and update it, bios reboot, etc. basically anything I found on the web.
 the pc also won't reboot but it will standby/hybernate correctly

Comment: When the screen goes purple, try press the escape key. This will reveal what's going on in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried issuing `sudo shutdown -h now` in terminal?  This should shut the computer down.  If you want to restart, substitute -h for -r.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lenovo B50-10 just like you and after days of research and trying all solutions out there I finally managed to solve the shutdown/reboot on this specific model. Updating the bios under windows didn't do the trick, I installed the latest kernel 4.4 and now I can smile again when I shutdown or reboot my lenovo B50-10. In fact in linuxmint which i intsalled the default kernel was 3.19.... generic.
You can easilly find out how to find your kernel version and how to download and install version 4.4. Hope this helps many out there!
P.S: I also noticed my wi fi connection is now more strong and stable after upgrading kernel